# HW Help Due Tonight. Char To Int (Help Returning Null)

Tags: c, pointers, char, int

I have a program that is supposed to convert char integers into actual integers. It has to be compatible with the Main method written by the professor. I think I have a solution to the actual conversion but I keep getting an infinite loop. I know I am supposed to return Null but I don't know how. Please can anyone help? This function is also supposed to ignore char letters and have a new space after every char letter. So 123fgf456 would print 123 (newline) 456.

```
The function I need help with.

    #include <stddef.h>
    /*
     * Scans inputString, ignoring leading whitespace (spaces, tabs, and newlines)
     * to find the first decimal digit, which it interprets as the most significant
     * digit of a decimal number, and continues scanning until finding the first
     * non-decimal digit. The digits found are converted to an integer, which is
     * stored in the location pointed to by integerPtr. This function returns a
     * pointer to the first non-digit after the first digit, unless a
     * non-whitespace, non-digit is encountered before a digit, in which case,
     * NULL is returned and the location pointed to by integerPtr is not changed.
     *
     * @param integerPtr A pointer to the integer in which to store the integer
     *        converted from the ASCII string
     * @return a pointer to the first non-digit character found if a number was
     *        successfully converted, NULL if not
     */

   char * asciiToInteger(char *inputString, int *integerPtr) {
    int i =0; int j=0; int num =0; char terminate; 
    if(inputString[i] == '\0') return NULL;
    if(inputString[i] == ' '){return NULL;}
    while(*inputString != '\0')
    {   

        if(*inputString >= '0' && *inputString <= '9')
        {
            if(inputString[i] == ' '){break;}
            num = num *10 + inputString[i]- '0';
            *integerPtr = num;
        }
        inputString++;

    }

    return inputString;
}




    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stddef.h> // for definition of NULL

    char * asciiToInteger(char inputString[], int *integerPtr);
    int main() {
       char inputBuffer[1024];
       char *ptr = NULL;
       int integer = 8888;
       while(fgets(inputBuffer, sizeof(inputBuffer), stdin)) {
          ptr = inputBuffer;
          int done = 0;
          while(!done) {
             char *newPtr = asciiToInteger(ptr, &integer);
             if(newPtr == NULL) {
                if(*ptr != '\0')
                   ++ptr; // Skip over offending character
                else
                   done = 1;
             } else {
                printf("%d\n", integer);
            ptr = newPtr;
             }
          }
       }

       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `asciiToInteger` never returns `NULL`, so the condition `newPtr == NULL` never happens, so you never set `done = 1`, so you have an infinite loop.  The comment "Skip over offending character" doesn't seem to corespond to what `asciiToInteger` actually does, which is that it always goes through to the end of the string, ignoring offending characters.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. So could I say if(inputString[i] == '\0')return NULL; could that work? I try to return NULL a variety of ways but what happens is that I'll input 123 and I get and output of '123' but the program keeps asking for input. It never ends. So I don't think I am implementing NULL correctly. Sorry I am new to C and pointers

Comment: You could, although there's nothing wrong with leaving the function as it is and changing the main code to be `if ( *newPtr == '\0' ) done = 1;`.  You shouldn't be doing anything with `ptr` at that point since it points to the start of the string still.

Comment: Thank you again. But my Professor doesn't want us changing the main program. I Can't really grasp the code yet (I'm used to Java) but I think it runs through a string until it hits a null terminator? He also told me to return a pointer to inputString where a letter left off. So If I have 123ef I would return a pointer to where the 'e' is but since I am new to pointers I don't have a clue how to do that.

Comment: OK. See the comment `@return a pointer to the first non-digit character found if a number was  successfully converted, NULL if not`. Your function should comply with that requirement.

Comment: Okay. Is the function I have right now okay? Do you think that I have to make major changes to get the program to work or am I close? Are pointers like Arrays in that they hold characters in elements? So if I have a char pointer that is set to an array that has the letters abc, does the pointer pointing to that array now contain those letters and if so can I iterate through them like an array? The part where it says return to the first non-digit character found is what I don't properly understand.

Comment: You're close. Pointers don't hold characters, they indicate another memory location where characters are held.  (With that location being the array defined by `char inputBuffer[1024];` in your code). Your function should `return InputString;` in the case of a number being read successfully (with InputString pointing to the first character after the last digit read -- which will be the terminator if there were no junk characters), or `return NULL;` if it could not read a number successfully

Comment: Thank you for your help. One thing he wants use to use is a text file that contains random numbers and letters. When I print the textfille I get repeats of the same line. So If a line in the file has 12 13 14 i get the output '121314 (newline) '121314' Ive updated the code to the new code but to be honest I am still at a lost.

Answer (score 1):

```
char * asciiToInteger(char *inputString, int *integerPtr) {
  int n = 0;
  int index = 0;
  while(*inputString != NULL) {
    if (*inputString >= '0' && *inputString <= '9') {
      n = n * 10 + *inputString - '0';
      ++inputString;
      integerPtr = &n;
      index += 1;
    } else if(*inputString < '0' || *inputString > '9') {
        if(*integerPtr) std::cout << *integerPtr << std::endl;
        n = 0;
        ++inputString;
    } else {
        if (*integerPtr) std::cout << *integerPtr << std::endl;
        ++inputString;
    }
}
  if(*integerPtr) std::cout << *integerPtr << std::endl;
  return inputString;
}
```

The above is a C++ implementation, here is an implementation using your printf:

```
char * asciiToInteger(char *inputString, int *integerPtr) {
  int n = 0;
  int index = 0;
  while(*inputString != NULL) {
    if (*inputString >= '0' && *inputString <= '9') {
      n = n * 10 + *inputString - '0';
      ++inputString;
      integerPtr = &n;
      index += 1;
    } else if(*inputString < '0' || *inputString > '9') {
        if(*integerPtr) printf("%d\n", *integerPtr);
        n = 0;
        ++inputString;
    } else {
        if (*integerPtr) printf("%d\n", *integerPtr);
        ++inputString;
    }
  }
  if(*integerPtr) printf("%d\n", *integerPtr);
  return inputString;
}
```

I find your prompt to be rather vague, but this should pass those test cases. Now you are also asked to return a pointer to the first non-digit after an initial digit. You can return &inputString[index - 1], however, you must not return early.

Answer (score 0):

You need a flag to remember whether you've seen any digits.  Then, if you see a non-digit, and you haven't seen any digits yet, bail out with `return NULL;` immediately.

Comment: Would something like if(*inputString < '0' && *inputString > '9'){return NULL;} be considered a flag? That way if any character that isnt a integer appears it returns NULL?

Comment: No, a flag needs to be an additional variable, not just a conditional.  After all, such a character is not an error _if you have already seen a digit_.

Comment: Hmm. I don't know if I ever learned how to used flags as part of a strategy. In this case I wouldn't know how to implement it. Is there any source you know where I could look into this? I've googled this problem non-stop or I would be on it myself. Or do you have any examples or how to use a flag? Thank you

Comment: A flag is nothing but a two-value variable.  Declare `int seenDigit=0;` and then, at the appropriate times, test it (`if(... && !seenDigit)` or so) and set it (`seenDigit=1;`).  C99 has a nicer `bool` type, if you're using that.

Comment: Does the Lack of a flag explain why I get repeating lines? So If I am supposed to print '1234' only one time it prints about 3 times. Is that due to a lack of a flag?

Comment: I don't immediately see the cause of the repetition.  Try writing a trivial program to call `asciiToInteger` exactly once so you can debug it more easily.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately the assignment due date time has already come and I was unable to finish it. Thank you for your help though I really appreciate it Ill try to look back on this code when I get another chance